# Nhibernate / hibernate discriminator in subclass

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, subclass, discriminator

I have a subclass with a discriminator, can i have another discriminator in a subclass
I'll try to explain
One discriminator is in Person Table may be type and i have two subclasses Student and teacher, in a student subclass i have different subclasses of student based on a different column in student record.
Now i am using joined subclass with  discriminator but i'm not be able to discriminate in a subclass

```
!------ Person
!-------------Student 
!--------------------Student type A
!--------------------Student type B
!-------------Teacher
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in the [documentation](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html):
"*Hibernate does not support mixing `<subclass>`, and `<joined-subclass>` and `<union-subclass>` mappings under the same root `<class>` element*" this I think is a troubkle for you, maybe you can break the joined subclass and use a  instaead ?
BTW nh is growing faster, sometimes faster than the doc, but I think this still apply to NH 3.1.0